# How to extract part of text from file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a number of files that contain the following text:

```
{"job_id":"ds_sdfsd38474","status":"X people in the queue before you..."}
```

where `X` changes from file to file from numbers between 1-100.

I'm wondering, how i extract from the files only:

```
ds_sdfsd38474
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\" '{print $4}' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F "\"" '{print $4}' yourfile
```

- `F` for setting the separator
- `$4` is the fourth column

Or you can use `cut`:

```
cut -d\" -f 4 yourfile
```

- `d` for setting the separator
- `f 4` is the fourth column